# WebCrypto WrapKey encrypted output format

Tags: aes-gcm, pkcs#8, webcrypto

I need to wrap an RSA Key in PKCS-8 format using an AES GCM key using the [WebCrypto API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey). I need the wrapped key to be interoperable with PKCS11 UnwrapKey API of HSMs (mainly Thales).

My question is, what is the output format of the wrapped key? Ideally it should be the [RFC-5989](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5958) Encrypted Private Key Info ASN.1 format, but it seems WebCrypto just outputs the encrypted bytes without any ASN.1 formatting.

Wondering if anyone knows what the format it? (Can't find it documented anywhere.)

Comment: You should specify the algorithm in question, [PKCS#11](https://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-curr/v3.0/os/pkcs11-curr-v3.0-os.html) defines different ones. WebCrypto implements AES-KW according to RFC 3394 ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/wrapKey#aes-kw)). The return is defined in [sec. 2.2.1 Key Wrap](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3394.html#section-2.2.1) and consists of the raw data. Incidentally, WebCrypto as low level API does not expose an ASN.1/DER encoder/decoder.